# Remote Desktop Access Ubuntu 17.10 - no desktop sharing option

Tags: remote-desktop, 17.10

I've been trying to remotely access my ubuntu 17.10. I started by installing teamviewer12 but that did not work. I then stumbled upon the desktop sharing article (https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/sharing-desktop.html) but apparently that does not exist in my installation. I did find sharing and file sharing under it but nothing else. 
I then installed gconftool-2 and tried to set the remote desktop option to true (but had no way of knowing whether it worked)
I then installed RealVNC connect but could not find any vnc dialog. I tried to run the vncliscensewiz from terminal and was able to sign in but it required sudo to complete and sudo vncliscensewiz did not work. 
Any solutions? or ideas on what to do ? or places I may have missed ? 
Thank you.

Comment: How about XRDP instead. It works fine.
See <http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=11184>.

Answer (score 4):

Just expanding [justen meltz](https://askubuntu.com/users/153744/justen-meltz) answer. The documentation does match when you switch to Xorg display server. That is quite easy as Xorg is already installed in ubuntu 17.10, but just in case, check this [quick reference:](https://itsfoss.com/switch-xorg-wayland/).

Once said that, I needed to configure remote access to my ubuntu 17.10 and still struggled a bit. I list below the references I used to get both XRDP and VNC running.

**XRDP (Assumes Xorg display server used)**

1. [Configure XRDP (written for 17.10)](http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=11336)

**VNC (Assumes Xorg display server used)**

4. Open "Ubuntu software", search for "Desktop Sharing" and install it.
5. [Configure "Desktop Sharing" and disable encryption.](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2016/07/remote-access-ubuntu-16-04/)
6. [You may also need to enable desktop sharing in ubuntu 17.10 sharing application](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/sharing-desktop.html).

Comment: Check Marc's link in the comments. You don't need to switch remote desktop environments.

Comment: Option for VNC on 17.04 don't work unfortunately, because on 17.04  you had default installed vnc4server. On 17.10 you haven't it.

Comment: This didn't work for me. I think there is a deeper issue.

Comment: mine says it's already installed. but it doesn't show up if I search 'Desktop Sharing' from the start menu in cinnamon

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem on one of the two systems I upgraded from 17.04 to 17.10. My oldest system, my desktop, had three options under Sharing. File Sharing, Screen Sharing, and Remote Login. My newer system only had two, and was missing Screen Sharing.

The difference was my old system was logging in with the setting Ubuntu on Xorg, while my new system was using something else. (Can't remember, think it was just Ubuntu). I switched it to match, and now the Screen Sharing option appears.

(To change this, at the login screen, click on the gear icon next to the Sign In button)

Looks like the Wayland display server doesn't support this feature yet, so choose something that uses Xorg. The Screen Sharing option appears with Gnome on Xorg and Ubuntu on Xorg. Pick you UI preference. The former is, obviously, Gnomish, while the latter is more like Unity.

The 17.10 release notes state, "On supported systems, Wayland is now the default display server. The older display server is still available: just choose Ubuntu on Xorg from the cog on the log in screen." That explains the difference between my old and new hardware.

I don't know when/if this support will be added for Wayland. Maybe it exists right now, and I just don't know how to use it, and someone with more knowledge will post a better solution to your problem.

Comment: Thanks. This didn't seem to work for me. I can't even ping other PC's in the network or ping this PC. Maybe the problem is somewhere else ?